# Getting Year & Date inside wpdb

Tags: wp-query

I am creating a shortcode to display data based on some options.

```
function dot_irt_top_posts ( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // get our variable from $atts
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'before' => '<li>',
        'after' => '</li>',
        'number' => '10',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'year' => '',
        'monthnum' => '',
        'show_count' => '1',
    ), $atts));

    global $wpdb;

    $request = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta";
    $request .= " WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id";

    if ($year != '') {
        $request .= " AND year=$year";
    }

    if ($year != '' && $monthnum != '') {
        $request .= " AND &monthnum='$monthnum'";
    } elseif ($monthnum != '') {
        $request .= " AND monthnum='$monthnum'";
    }

    $request .= " AND post_status='publish' AND post_type='$post_type' AND meta_key='_recommended'";
    $request .= " ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT $number";
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($request);

    $return = '';


    foreach ($posts as $item) {
        $post_title = stripslashes($item->post_title);
        $permalink = get_permalink($item->ID);
        $post_count = $item->meta_value;
        $return .= $before.'<a href="' . $permalink . '" title="' . $post_title.'" rel="nofollow">' . $post_title . '</a> ';

        if ( $show_count == '1') {
            $return .= '<span class="votes">' . $post_count . '</span> ';
        }

        //$return .= get_the_post_thumbnail($item->ID, 'showcase-thumbnail');
        $return .= $after;

    }
    return $return;

}
add_shortcode('irt_top_posts','dot_irt_top_posts');
```

And then the shortcode would be like:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[irt_top_posts post_type='showcase' number='10' monthnum='9']"); ?>
```

**UPDATED QUESTION's**

1. There seems to be some issue with my query. The Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters has an example for using the date to retrive results when using WP_Query. I want to know what changes I need to make to my code to have YEAR or MONTH in the query when getting results
2. I noticed most shortcodes when communicating with database use wpdb class and not wp_query. Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: Show us the results of `$wpdb->last_error` and `$wpdb->last_query` as edit to your question. Also your MarkUp has problems. Please edit your question and fix that.

Comment: Ok finally got it from here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56966/custom-wpdb-query-for-custom-post-type-by-category

Answer (score 0):

You mention the Codex page for `WP_Query` but you are not using `WP_Query`. You are using [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

`WP_Query` is a very complicated class for querying the WordPress tables for post (CPT) data. `wpdb` is a lightweight wrapper around PHP SQL functions. With `WP_Query` you can pass arguments like `monthnum` because the `WP_Query` class converts the argument into proper SQL.

With `wpdb` *you* have to write the SQL. `$wpdb->get_results` essentially passes your SQL through to the database engine. If you look at the [database descriptions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), there is no column named `monthnum`. You are asking MySQL to pull data from a column that does not exist. That is why you get an error.

You need to write valid SQL-- [look at the date manipulation functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)-- or use `WP_Query` whose Codex page you are already investigating. The latter is the better choice.

Comment: thanks for that. My question was wrong so have updated it. Would it be possible for you to let me know the right query to use to get posts by year or by year+month.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer from another post [Custom $wpdb Query for Custom Post Type by Category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56966/custom-wpdb-query-for-custom-post-type-by-category):

```
function dot_irt_top_posts ( $atts, $content = null ) {

// get our variable from $atts
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'before' => '<li>',
    'after' => '</li>',
    'number' => '10',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'year' => '',
    'monthnum' => '',
    'show_count' => '1',
), $atts));

global $wpdb;

$request = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta";
$request .= " WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id";

if ($year != '') {
    $request .= " AND YEAR(post_date) = '$year'";
}

if ($monthnum != '') {
    $request .= " AND MONTH(post_date) = '$monthnum'";
}

$request .= " AND post_status='publish' AND post_type='$post_type' AND meta_key='_recommended'";
$request .= " ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT $number";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($request);

$return = '';


foreach ($posts as $item) {
    $post_title = stripslashes($item->post_title);
    $permalink = get_permalink($item->ID);
    $post_count = $item->meta_value;
    $return .= $before.'<a href="' . $permalink . '" title="' . $post_title.'" rel="nofollow">' . $post_title . '</a> ';

    if ( $show_count == '1') {
        $return .= '<span class="votes">' . $post_count . '</span> ';
    }

    //$return .= get_the_post_thumbnail($item->ID, 'showcase-thumbnail');
    $return .= $after;

}
return $return;

}
add_shortcode('irt_top_posts','dot_irt_top_posts');
```